# SQL Agrupar consulta com mais de um atributo distinto

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, group-by

Tenho uma aplicação que gera aproximadamente 25000 registros por dia no BD. Isso irá gerar uma grande quantidade de id's por dia no BD do usuário.

Segundo a regra de negócio do usuário, apenas as inspeções reprovadas (`is_ok = 0`), devem ser registradas, as que foram aprovadas (`is_ok = 1`) poderão ser descartadas.

Porém o usuário necessita de um relatório com alguns dados da produção diária feita, como o total de inspeções por modelo feito em cada dia, quantas foram  aprovadas ou reprovadas,
que horas foi feita a primeira inspeção e que horas foi feita a última inspeção.

Pensando em eliminar o fato da geração do grande volume de id's gerados por dia,
ao final de cada dia eu poderia ler essa tabela de INSPECOES, 
gravar as que foram reprovadas em uma tabela (INSPECOES_REPROVADAS), 
gravar os dados da produção diária em outra tabela (PRODUCAO_DIARIA), apagar a todos os registros da tabela INSPECOES,  e por fim, reiniciar o contador de ID'S preparando assim a tabela para começar um novo registro de inspeções com o id começando novamente em 1.

Preciso fazer um job em um servidor MySql para executar essa tarefa.

Vale lembrar que tenho que gravar as inspeções agrupadas por data e modelo, ou seja, numa mesma data tenho inspeções de mais de um modelo. Não posso somar inspeções de modelos diferentes para uma mesma dada.

Veja o exemplo:

```
INSPECOES
=========
id      is_ok   serial_number       date_inspection         path            mode    models_id   shift_id    line_id
1       1       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-27 09:50:36                     1       7           1           1
2       1       BR11S140325004663   2014-08-27 09:51:01                     1       7           1           1
3       1       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-27 10:16:39                     1       7           1           1
4       1       BR11S140325004663   2014-08-27 10:17:28                     1       7           1           1
5       0       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-27 10:41:35     c:/bla.abc      1       7           1           1
6       0       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-27 10:42:19     c:/bla.abc      1       7           1           1
7       0       BR11S140325004663   2014-08-27 10:42:34     c:/bla.abc      1       7           1           1
8       1       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-27 11:05:19                     1       7           1           1
9       1       BR11S140325004599   2014-08-27 11:07:33                     1       6           1           1
10      1       BR11S140325004599   2014-08-27 11:30:16                     1       6           1           1
11      1       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-27 11:36:42                     1       6           1           1
12      0       BR11S140325004666   2014-08-27 12:40:14     c:/bla.abc      1       6           1           1
13      0       BR11S140325004663   2014-08-27 12:42:34     c:/bla.abc      1       6           1           1
14      1       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 08:55:12                     1       7           1           1
15      1       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 08:56:22                     1       7           1           1
16      1       BR11S140325004663   2014-08-28 08:57:44                     1       7           1           1
17      0       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 08:59:12     c:/bla.abc      1       7           1           1
18      0       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 08:59:40     c:/bla.abc      1       7           1           1
19      1       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 10:00:00     c:/bla.abc      1       8           1           1
20      0       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 10:00:12     c:/bla.abc      1       8           1           1
21      1       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 10:01:30     c:/bla.abc      1       8           1           1
22      0       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 10:01:40     c:/bla.abc      1       8           1           1
23      1       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 10:08:40     c:/bla.abc      1       8           1           1
24      0       BR11S140325004685   2014-08-28 10:09:40     c:/bla.abc      1       8           1           1

PRODUCAO_DIARIA
===============
id  date        total_inspections   models_id   start_time  end_time
1   2014-08-27  8                   7           09:50:36    11:05:19
2   2014-08-27  5                   6           11:07:33    12:42:34
3   2014-08-28  5                   7           08:55:12    08:59:40
4   2014-08-28  6                   8           10:00:00    10:09:40
```

O máximo que consegui foi fazer uma query que me mostra as inspeções, mas ela não contabiliza todos os modelos separados. Veja:

```
select date_inspection, models_id, count(models_id)
from 
(
    select *
    from 
    (
        select*from Inspecoes where is_ok = 0
    ) as t
    group by date_inspection
)as t
group by models_id;
```

Porém o retorno dessa query é :

```
date_inspection     models_id   count(models_id)
2014-08-27 12:40:14 6           2
2014-08-27 10:41:35 7           5
2014-08-28 10:00:12 8           3
```

Ela volta as contagens erradas e ainda faltam modelos.

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Para o start_time e end_time use o MIN e o MAX respectivamente.

Comment: Ok @Motta, mas ele pega os Min e o Max dá seleção de inspeções que estão com problema pois eu passei o filtro `where is_ok = 0` . Na verdade eu preciso dos horários de início e término da tabela INSPECOES antes de passar o filtro. Como posso fazer isso nessa consulta?

Comment: select date_inspection, models_id, min(date_inspection) start_time , max(date_inspection) end_time , count(models_id) 
from ( select * 
       from ( select *
              from Inspecoes 
              where is_ok = 0 ) as t 
group by date_inspection )as t group by models_id; sem levar em conta a questão do filtro que não entendi , o que indica o is_ok !?

Comment: @Motta, obrigado pelas dicas. Eu editei a questão para melhorar o entendimento para você e para outros usuários também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo o que entendi, seu problema está em separar os registros por modelo e pela data.
Sua consulta está agrupando apenas pelo modelo. Para que as datas sejam levadas em conta ao agrupar, você precisa adicioná-las ao `group by` antes de agrupar por modelo.

Ficaria assim

```
SELECT
    `date_inspection` AS 'date', 
    count( `models_id` ) AS 'total_inspections'
    `models_id`,
    DATE_FORMAT( min( `date_inspection` ) ,'%H:%i:%s' ) AS 'start_time',
    DATE_FORMAT( max( `date_inspection` ) ,'%H:%i:%s' ) AS 'end_time'
FROM `Inspecoes`
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(`date`),
    MONTH(`date`),
    DAY(`date`),
    `model_id`;
```

O retorno dever ser como desejado.

Caso seja importante saber o número de inspeções que ocorreram bem ou não, vc pode adicionar um contador condicional, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
    `date_inspection` AS 'date', 
    COUNT( `models_id` ) AS 'total_inspections'
    `models_id`,
    DATE_FORMAT( MIN( `date_inspection` ), '%H:%i:%s' ) AS 'start_time',
    DATE_FORMAT( MAX( `date_inspection` ), '%H:%i:%s' ) AS 'end_time',
    COUNT( IF( `is_ok` = "1", 1, null ) ) AS 'success', 
    COUNT( IF( `is_ok` = "0", 1, null) ) AS 'error'
FROM `Inspecoes`
GROUP BY
    YEAR( `date` ),
    MONTH( `date` ),
    DAY( `date` ),
    `model_id`;
```

Obs.: Observe que deixo claro na consulta o que é tabela, campo, valor ou palavra-chave usando aspas, apóstrofo ou letra maiúscula. Isso não só ajuda na leitura como evita erros de execução da query. Recomendo começar a fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Perfeito @marcusagm. Exatamente o que eu precisava. Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom! As ordens =]